# Closed Form for sum $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{1}{3^n+n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I encountered this sum in my math class and I don't know how to get a closed form. I've tried using the residue theorem and it hasn't gone anywhere, although I'm guessing that's how one would be found. Any ideas?

Comment: there is nothing to solve, there is not a simple form

Comment: How do you know? What do you mean?

Comment: solve has a different meaning, What i know is not important, i can not prove what i said, so i really should have not said it. In my unproved opinion is too ugly to have a closed form, but math is not about opinions.

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut Put another way, what makes you believe there is a "nice" closed-form? (for some suitable definition of "nice").

Comment: Ok. I edited my question to make it clearer that I'm looking for a closed form and not an abstract "solution". I feel like it should have a closed form, but as you said math is not about opinions.

Comment: @ClementC. I'm not sure if it has a closed form, but I think since it's such a simple series it probably should. If you don't think it does, why not?

Comment: Oh, I just have a completely heuristic argument: most things I have seen either provably have no simple closed forms or, if they have, have some closed form out of my reach. But this is in no way a proof: simply, if you knew for sure it has one (e.g., it is from an assignment) then this would definitely close the debate.

Comment: @ClementC. You might be right. The assignment only asked for a proof of  convergence (very simple) and not a closed form, but I thought it was an interesting series.

Comment: Derivative is uglier that original, and doesnt exist an antiderivative writable in simple functions. Little hope for this series to have a closed form. Maybe writing interior as a series and trying to apply (if possible) some theorem to swap summation, or a change of variable... anyway seems very ugly.

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut: Even the simpler series $~\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{3^n+1}~$ does not possess a meaningful closed form, but can only be expressed in terms of the special [q-polygamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html).