# Calculating $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{{1}}{n+3^n} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

I was able to prove this sum

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{{1}}{n+3^n}$$

is convergent through the comparison test but I don't get how to find its sum.

Comment: This is such an interesting problem, but can you please provide more context? What class are you taking?

Comment: I encountered a very similar situation a long time ago (I was asked to show it converged and was curious about its sum) and asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1672121/closed-form-for-sum-sum-infty-n-1-frac13nn). No answer was found, but you might find the comments interesting/useful.

Comment: Im in calc 2, my teacher didnt do a very good job of explaining this stuff and kinda rushed through the material since its the end of the semester.

Comment: @FordDavis Ask your teacher about the question again. It's quite unlikely they expect for you to find the sum. Or maybe the question was $\frac{1}{n3^n}$, which has a much [nicer answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1709176/find-the-sum-of-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n3n).

Comment: What about this one: Is there any  non-zero function $f(n) $ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1} {f(n) +3^n}$ has an okay closed form?

Comment: Here is a picture of the assignment https://ibb.co/dsNbcnx

Comment: @Zacky There are some trivial choices like $f(n) = 2^n - 3^n$.

Comment: There's something odd about this assignment.  Part b) can be summed in closed form, but it takes techniques way beyond calc 2.  Are you perhaps supposed to *approximate* the sums.  I definitely second @TobyMak's advice: ask your teacher about it.

Comment: @Daniel Or $f(n)=3^n$

Comment: @FordDavis For the ones that converge, b) and g) look a little odd. However, d) is definitely solvable.

Comment: Haha I overtought that, maybe I should've added non-trivial function $f(n) $. @Davis g)  also looks unsolvable in a closed form.

Comment: @saulspatz Part B) I actually asked her about yesterday because I couldnt figure it out and she told me to integrate it. I got [arctan(infinity)-arctan(1)]= pi/2 for that part.

Comment: To get an idea about b) look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1064217/515527

Comment: @Zacky the answer given there is way above my head, I barely even know what coth is.

Comment: As noted by Carl, this question already exists ... https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1672121/442 but even that has no answer in nearly 3 years.  No answer = cannot mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: Well, integrating it will given an approximation to the sum, but sums and integrals are different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What we can obtain, also by hand, is a reasonable estimation for example by

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{{1}}{n+3^n}\approx 0.392<\sum_{n=1}^3\frac{{1}}{n+3^n}+\sum_{n=4}^\infty\frac{{1}}{3^n}=$$$$=\frac14+\frac1{11}+\frac1{30}+\frac32-1-\frac13-\frac1{9}-\frac1{27}\approx 0.393$$

Comment: I dont remember us going over approximating the sum, but this might be what she wanted. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @FordDavis Yes indeed in that case seems convenient use the fact that $3^n$ is larger than $n$ also for $n$ small to obtain a god estimation for the series.